# adding multiple items to shopping cart using session through servlet

Tags: java, session, servlets

**I want to add multiple items to add to the shopping cart using session.i wrote the code only to add a single item to the cart. can u plz suggest how i can add multiple items.plz??**

```
String name=req.getParameter("n");
        String cost=req.getParameter("c");

        HttpSession s=req.getSession();
        s.setAttribute("name",name);
        s.setAttribute("cost",cost);
        out.println("item successfully added to cart");
        out.println("\n<a href=\'viewserv\'>view cart</a>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `List` to add multiple cart. To store both name and cost, use a model class `Cart` with these properties.

```
class Cart{
   String name;
   double cost;
  // Getter & Setter

}
```

Now add multiple cart values to `List`. Here is sample code snippet.

```
  String name=req.getParameter("n");
  String cost=req.getParameter("c");

  HttpSession s=req.getSession();

  List<Cart> list= (List<Cart>) s.getAttribute("list");

  if(list==null){
    list =new ArrayList<>();
  }
  // Add the name & cost to List
  list.add(new Cart(name, cost));

  s.setAttribute("list",list);
```

**Edit:**

To display the List value, you need to iterate the List

```
 for(Cart cart : list){
   out.println("Name "+ cart.getName());
   out.println("Cost "+ cart.getCost());
 }
```

Comment: old one might be better

Comment: what about getattribute?? if i want to show the result

Comment: @user3717775, `getAttribute` is for to get previously added list from session to add new value to list or display result.

Comment: HttpSession s1=req.getSession();
     List<Cart> list1=new ArrayList<Cart>();
     list1=ArrayList<Cart>(s1.getAttribute("list"));
     out.println();

Comment: i m writing the above code to display the result.can u plz tell me what is the error in it?

Comment: out.println(list1);at the end

Comment: @user3717775, You need to iterate over List and display the result.